# Print the result of a Python def

Tags: python, function, exif

I want to read the date and time of a image by using Pillow. 
And now I want to print the result of the def to be shure I got the Date and Time. But when I type `print(defname)` I just get some weird numbers as the output.

My code:

```
import os
import time
import shutil 
import re
from PIL import Image, ExifTags
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def get_date_taken(path):
    return Image.open(r"E:\insert_folder\DSC_3389.jpg")._getexif()[36867]

print(get_date_taken)
```

One more thing... If you understand what I want to do and if you understand my code, could you pls check if there is any fault in my code?
Thanks to you guys! <3

Comment: Please show us the code around `print(defname)`

Comment: May I kindly suggest you do the [official python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the function, you are just printing a pointer to that function - this the memory address where the function is stored. In order to execute the function, add parenthesis.

`get_date_taken("your\path\here")`

Also, what you are calling def and defname are called functions in Python.

Comment: There's no pointers in Python - what the OP is printing is the function object itself. The fact that the string representation of a Python function includes the function object's uid is just an implementation detail, and the fact that _in CPython_ objects uids are their memory address is even more of an implementation detail (other Python implementation - Jython, IronPython, etc - may use anything else as objects uids).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I will delete my answer.

Comment: DONT !!! it's not a bad answer, it just needs to be edited to be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute your function:

It is

```
print(get_date_taken(""))
```

not

```
print(get_date_taken)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are just printing the definition of your function. To print the return value you have to call your function with the path:

```
print(get_date_taken("path of your image"))
```

Comment: the OP are not printing "the definition of" the function, they are printing the function object itself (or more exactly the string representation of the function).

Answer (score 0):

Functions take magnificent things called parameters. You need to fill `get_date_taken` with a parameter such as `get_date_taken("IMG_0001")`